# Can I create a const object in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to create a **const** object inside my SystemVerilog class. Does SystemVerilog support const objects (and how?), or does it only support const primitive types.

I'd like to do something like:

```
const my_object MY_CONST;

const begin
    MY_CONST = new();
    MY_CONST.param1 = "value1";
    MY_CONST.param2 = "value2";
end
```

Comment: I see reference to it on [SystemVerilog.org](http://www.systemverilog.org/pdf/1a_DesignOverview.pdf#page=14), but the VCS compiler doesn't seem to accept it in 2009 or 2011 versions of the tool.

Comment: Perhaps `const` is in the System Verilog spec', but it isn't implemented for your compiler.  I don't think any of the three major SV simulators (VCS, NCSim, ModelSim) support _all_ of the SV spec.  They each support a different subset at the moment, afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create constant class instances.

> An instance of a class (an object handle) can also be declared with
>   the const keyword.
>
> ```
> const class_name object = new(5,3);
> ```
>
> In other words,
>   the object acts like a variable that cannot be written. The arguments
>   to the new method shall be constant expressions (see 11.2.1). The
>   members of the object can be written (except for those members that
>   are declared const).

Answer (score 2):

I would have liked to comment on Adam12's answer, but I can't so I'll post a new answer instead, sigh!

In SV `MY_CONST` would only be a constant handle. So probably you can't assign another object to the handle, but the contents of the object being pointed to by the handle can still be modified.

I haven't heard of any `const begin ... end` construct. I would think that there is a restriction on calling `new` — it should be called at the time of assigning to the `const` handle, or `new` can be called in the constructor if the `const` handle is a member of a class. The member functions of the `const` handle could be called anywhere, I would guess.